# No provider for BsModalService, what I need to change?

Tags: angular

**usermodule.ts**

Imports:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UsersRoutingModule } from './users-routing.module';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list/user-list.component';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [UserListComponent],
```

***Should I add some in imports?***

```
   imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot()
   ],
```

**Should I add some in providers?**

```
  providers: 
 })
  export class UsersModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, read how to make questions or you will get negative votes. You should put what you want and what you trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

```
imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
```

In latest version of angular `imports` is more preferable, for more [reference](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a provider for BsModalService

```
providers: [BsModalService]
```

Comment: in my case it is B**s**ModalService. Small letter `s`.

Answer (score 1):

if there are others with the same problem, here is the solution worked for me:
**I had to remove the .angular\cache and it worked again as it should.**

For me, everything was working as it should, but suddenly I got the error and couldn't start the app until I deleted the cache. I hope this answer will help somebody in the future.